# Replace big HTML Code - C#

Tags: c#

I have an app that can get incoming shouts and send shouts on a website's shoutbox, in that shoutbox HTML is used to show to Smileys:

```
<img src=\"http:\/\/www.darkbox.nl\/board\/images\/smilies\/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" \/>
```

That is how it shows up in my program.
I tried this to find and replace the HTML code with ':)'

```
                if(s.Message.Contains("< img src =\"http:\/\/www.darkbox.nl\/board\/images\/smilies\/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" \/>"))
            {
                s.Message.Replace("<img src=\"http:\/\/www.darkbox.nl\/board\/images\/smilies\/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" \/>", ":)");
            }
```

Only that doesn't work, i get 7 errors, all 'Unrecognized escape sequence'
I also tried `@""` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape sequence it's complaining about is `\/` - you don't need to escape `/`:

```
if(s.Message.Contains("< img src =\"http://www.darkbox.nl/board/images/smilies/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" />"))
{
    s.Message.Replace("<img src=\"http://www.darkbox.nl/board/images/smilies/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" />", ":)");
}
```

But while we're at it, there's no point doing a check with `Contains` first - if it's not there, it won't get replaced, may as well just called `.Replace` without checking:

```
s.Message.Replace("<img src=\"http://www.darkbox.nl/board/images/smilies/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" />", ":)");
```

However, you should also note that `Replace` doesn't modify the original string, you need to also assign it to something, possibly `s.Message` though it depends exactly what else is going on in your code:

```
s.Message = s.Message.Replace("<img src=\"http://www.darkbox.nl/board/images/smilies/smile.gif\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" class=\"smilie smilie_1\" />", ":)");
```

Comment: That should work i guess, but now i get another error saying: Property or Indexer ''DBShout" cannot be assigned to -- it's read only, cant put the full code here

Comment: @Remi _"possibly `s.Message` though it depends exactly what else is going on in your code"_ So not `s.Message` then.  Looks like you'll need a local variable to hand off the updated message to your textbox.

Comment: I tried this, https://gyazo.com/ffca0aa9f475292e4bdfd39e740d7007. But still the HTML code comes up in the richTextBox

Comment: @Remi then your html string isn't exactly what you think it is.  Your original question here was about escape characters - you're going to have to do some more debugging to find out what actual data you're dealing with, but that's probably a different question to what you originally asked here.

Comment: I thinki did it.. I just took the HTML code apart and replaced those little parts! It doesnt look clean, but it works :s

Answer (score 0):

You don't need escape chars at all. Just use forward slash like that :

```
http://www.darkbox.nl/board/images/smilies...
```

Only backward slash needs escaping

Comment: But i can't replace that with :) because that is not how it shows in my program, i don't want to use those escape chars, but they are already there, and if i want to remove those chars, i can't replace it anymore